# Using NSPredicateEditor, is there a way to get all of the Finder search categories for free?

Tags: cocoa, nspredicate, finder, nspredicateeditor, nsruleeditor

I'm adding an NSPredicateEditor to my app to allow the user to seach for specific files and categories of files.

The default NSPredicateEditor template from Inteface Builder adds a control containing only "name", "address", and "sign" categories. I'm looking for more specific categories.

[image: default interface builder NSPredicateEditor]

I know that I can add menu items to these menus in Interface Builder, but I would greatly prefer not to maintain a list myself of all of the various categories and values for file searches.

In Finder, a great variety of categories and values can be added to searches.

[image: default categories for Finder searches]

Using saving this search then using "Get Info" on the saved seach folder reveals the predicate used to generate the Finder's NSPredicateEditor:

```
((** = "this*"cdw) &&
(kMDItemContentTypeTree = "public.png"cd) &&
InRange(kMDItemLastUsedDate,$time.today(-2d),$time.today(+1d)) &&
InRange(kMDItemContentModificationDate,$time.today(-4d),$time.today(+1d)) &&
InRange(kMDItemContentCreationDate,$time.today(-8d),$time.today(+1d)) &&
(kMDItemDisplayName = "*screenshot*"cd) && (kMDItemTextContent = "content*"cdw))
```

Clicking the "Other" category type brings up a menu with a wide variety of even *more* specific categories.

[image: Other Categories for Finder Search]

My question is if this same complicated and customized NSPredicateEditor from Finder be added "for free" to my app? Or will I need to declare and then maintain a list of all of the search types my app supports?

Answer (score 1):

> My question is if this same complicated and customized NSPredicateEditor from Finder be added "for free" to my app?

No, this `NSRuleEditor` is part of the app Finder.

Yes, with a few extra's. A similar editor is in the Open/Save File panel.

Comment: Thanks. What are you referring to when you say "Yes, with a few extras."?

Comment: You don't only get the rule editor, you also get the rest of the Open/Save File panel.

Comment: Are you saying there's a panel that can be added for free to any app, that includes predicates/rules as well as open/save? If so, which class is that?

Comment: `NSOpenPanel` and its superclass `NSSavePanel`.

Comment: Hmm. I still don't understand how those panels relate to rules/predicates. I don't seem to see any support for a predicate in those panels? Do you have a screenshot?

Comment: Expand the panel (little button "v") and type something in the search field.

Answer (score 1):

A little late, but you should look at MDSchema.h. MDSchemaCopyAllAttributes will return the entire supported Spotlight schema, MDSchemaCopyDisplayNameForAttribute will return the display name for the list, and MDSchemaCopyDisplayDescriptionForAttribute will return the value types for each item in the schema. From this you can build your own NSRuleEditor. NSPredicateEditor would be harder, since you are getting a lot of behavior built in that you then have to override, but probably still possible.